# Creating a Zuma-like web game - which technology to use?

Tags: java, flash, web

I'd like to port my [Zuma](http://www.popcap.com/games/zumas-revenge/online)-like game to browsers. It's not really complex 2D arcade game, just some animations and particle systems - really similar in complexity to the one I linked to.
I'm wondering what technology should I use. I'm thinking about Java, Flash or maybe some solution working without a plugin (SVG, Canvas?). The cost of the technology is also really important to me (I'd prefer a free solution of course, but don't know if it's possible).

It's really probable that I'll also port the game to Android and iPhone. Maybe if I picked Java, I could write one version that would work on both: browsers and Android phones?

Sorry for my lack of knowledge, my situation is pretty weird now, since I got an interesting offer from a producer.

Comment: You listed the pros and cons pretty well. There is no single best technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to port game to the web (e.g. it is not a weekend project of yours), it is a real project which is supposed to be used by many users, and you are not paid specifically by Google or Microsoft to make this game using JS+canvas, you should choose flash. Making professional games with HTML5, which works on every browser is very time consuming task. Also I'm not really sure it is possible to make HTML5 game without Flash, as far as I know web versions  Angry Birds and Cut the Rope are using flash player for sounds (since there is no low latency sound api in browser).

So this is one of the reasons why to use Flash. Another reason is that Flash is used for creating games for very long time, there are lot of resources, game engines , tutorials, user groups and etc.

Also you don't need to buy anything from Adobe to start building games, there free editors (like [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/)) or more advanced commercial IDEs(f.e. [Astella](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/10/jetbrains-introduces-astella-a-new-ide-for-actionscript-flex-air-and-html5-development/) from JetBrains).

Answer (score 1):

HTML5, javascript and CSS3 will make your game run anywhere, its free and its the future.

Answer (score 1):

HTML, CSS, JQuery seems to be the emerging way of creating anything on the web. This includes games. Yes, this technology hasn't been "perfected" yet,  but I would at least spend sometime with it. Hey it's free, portable, and is always improving.

I found the following link on Google by "searching HTML5 game engine". http://impactjs.com/

Someone posted an all CSS game on YCombinator a few days ago. It's amazing what you can do nowadays!
http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3483662
http://jsrun.it/GeckoTang/4rXg/